# By ID, uniquely expanding multiple columns

Tags: stata

Let's say I have this dataset.

```
id  headquarter_name    subsidiary_name
A     Apple                 Apple
A     Apple Inc.            Apple
A     Apple Computer        Apple corp.
B     Microsoft             MS
B     MS                    MS
```

For your convenience, I created this dataset [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b2n3zcdze4mt6gm/ExampleStackoverflowData.dta?dl=0):

I want to make, for each id, just a list of "unique" names distributed across widely like this.

```
id   Name1        Name2         Name3          Name4
A    Apple      Apple Inc.  Apple Computer   Apple corp.
B    Microsoft     MS
```

It needs to be unique. "Apple" appears many times, but it was included just once, for example.

To make this, the only thing that I could think about was this so far, which, of course, doesn't do what I want to do.

```
collapse (first) headquarter_name subsidiary_name,by(id)
```

Comment: Thanks for the attachment, but the `stata` tag wiki explains how best to show data examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
clear
input str1 id  str42 ( headquarter_name    subsidiary_name) 
A     "Apple"                 "Apple"
A     "Apple Inc."            "Apple"
A     "Apple Computer"        "Apple corp."
B     "Microsoft"             "MS"
B     "MS"                    "MS"
end 
stack id headquarter_name id subsidiary_name, into(id name) clear 
drop _stack
duplicates drop
bysort id (name) : gen which = _n
reshape wide name, i(id) j(which)
list 

     +--------------------------------------------------------+
     | id   name1            name2        name3         name4 |
     |--------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |  A   Apple   Apple Computer   Apple Inc.   Apple corp. |
  2. |  B      MS        Microsoft                            |
     +--------------------------------------------------------+
```

A variant on this would add sorting by frequency of mentions before dropping of duplicates.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you!